# Making a new property from the parents property name through SQL on a noSQL type document

Tags: sql, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to write a SQL query to make a subproperty of a property part of a "new" property within that respective subproperty. For example a sample document looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "StudentId": "12",
        "Classes" : {
            "Math":{
               "Location": "RoomA",
               "Grade": "A"
            },
            "Science": {
                "Location": "RoomB",
                "Grade": "B"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**GOAL**

The goal is to query that document to get a result like the following:

```
[
    {
        "StudentId": "12",
        "Classes" : {
                "Name": "Math",
                "Location": "RoomA",
                "Grade": "A"
                },
                {
                "Name": "Science",
                "Location": "RoomB",
                "Grade": "B"
                }
        }
    }
]
```

My first step is figuring out how to actually grab the respective class names without the actual properties. My following SQL query:

```
SELECT t.StudentId, {"Name": t.Classes.Math} FROM t WHERE t.StudentId= "12"
```

grabbed the whole structure within 'Math' for example:

```
[
    {
        "TenantId": "12",
        "Classes": {
            "Name": {
                "Location": "RoomA",
                "Grade": "A"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Edit: I am using this to query CosmosDB documents

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement needs to change the original structure of document which is not be touched in the sql query.

I suggest you using cosmos db stored procedure as workaround,please see my sample code:

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT r.StudentId,r.Classes FROM r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            returnArray = [];
            for(var i =0;i<feed.length;i++){
                classArray = [];   
                for(var key in feed[i].Classes)
                {
                   var map = {};
                   map["Name"] = key;          
                   map["Location"] = feed[i].Classes[key].Location;
                   map["Grade"] = feed[i].Classes[key].Grade;
                   classArray.push(map);
                }
                feed[i].Classes = classArray;
            }         
            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.'); }
```

***Output:***

[image]